# Take arguments from individual columns of dataframe, output into list, then bind into dataframe

Tags: r

I've been working on this for hours! Someone was kind enough to help me along with the function- which works!

```
rnormfunc <- function(n.arg, mean.arg, sd.arg, percentdist.arg){  ## main function; first three inputs are for rnorm values, percentdist.arg is percent from mean argument

    rnorm1 <- rnorm(n.arg, mean.arg, sd.arg) # creates a vector holding values in normal distrib. from inputs 
    j <- (percentdist.arg/100)  # changes percent distance into decimal value
    b <- mean.arg*(1+j)  # max percent distance from mean
    g <- mean.arg*(1-j) # min percent distance from mean

    total.in.range <- sum(rnorm1 >= g  & rnorm1 <= b)
    return(total.in.range) # sum of number of values within percentage range                
}
```

I need to take this function and apply the following matrix/dataframe as arguments. I've been trying various approaches- basically, the apply() family of functions. Specifically, mapply() or the by() function.  I'm struggling with whether I should be working with a matrix, or a dataframe- and for what reason.

```
samp.vect <- c(1,1.96,3.92) #three randomized percent distances from mean
r.dat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 101, ncol = 4)
colnames(r.dat) <- c("n.arg","mean.arg","sd.arg","percentdist.arg")
r.dat[,1] = seq(from <-1, to <- 100001,by =1000) #1 to 100001 by 1000, first column
r.dat[,2] = 0  # second column is mean, always zero
r.dat[1:50,3] = c(1)   # column 3 rows 1 to 50 has sd = 1
r.dat[51:101,3]  = c(2)  # column 3 rows 51:101 has sd = 2
r.dat[,4]  = sample(samp.vect,101, replace = TRUE) 
head(r.dat)
tail(r.dat)
```

which produces this:

```
> head(r.dat)
     n.arg mean.arg sd.arg percentdist.arg
[1,]     1        0      1            3.92
[2,]  1001        0      1            1.00
[3,]  2001        0      1            1.96
[4,]  3001        0      1            1.96
[5,]  4001        0      1            3.92
[6,]  5001        0      1            1.00
```

So I'm stuck- I feel like I'm hung up on either using a matrix, or dataframe to start. I get the feeling like some type of apply(rnormfunc, r.dat$n.arg, r.dat$n.mean...) could be the way but I don't have a grasp of what to do.

Then manipulate one of these data structures where each of the four columns needs to be used as arguments for the above rnormfunc() by row.  Then I want to use cbind() to attach it to the matrix/data frame.

Gotta say, this is incredibly frustrating, but incredibly fun to get right and learn at the same time! Also, please feel free to critique my etiquette/post to make it easier for feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I only tested this on the first 6 cases(rows) but this should be generalizable:

```
apply( head(r.dat), 1, function(x) 
            rnormfunc( x['n.arg'], x['mean.arg'], x['sd.arg'], x['percentdist.arg']) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looking at the apply() code you put forth, and stuff I've found elsewhere, it makes sense and should work.  However, when I run it, it just returns zeros.  You call the apply() function, with arguments being the data structure (matrix in this case), MARGIN = 1 for applying across rows, and then a function (x) calling my function with dimnames for each argument input.

Comment: When I look at the actual content of that function, it appears to me that those 0's are the correct answer for the algorithm you provided. Why should any case be both greater and less than 0???? You say it "works", but I doubt that it "works correctly".

Comment: @PeterSmith  If I manually input four unique arguments into rnormfunc(), it returns a single value which has to be less than n.arg, and varies depending on the sd.arg.  and percentdist.arg.  Does that not seem to be the case for you?

Comment: I'm not sure who Peter is but I think _you_ should put the actual values for the first couple of lines of data into your function and see what you get. I think it will be all 0's. I think your logical operator should be an "|" if you are trying to get the number outside the bounds and you should swap the directions of the inequalities if you want the number inside the bounds. And in the future you should say what you goals are.

Comment: nevermind the Peter thing. Thanks for your help. I created a matrix "r.dat" with four columns (n.arg= sample size, mean.arg = mean, sd.arg is the standard deviation, and percentdist.arg is number of values within a certain percent of the mean, which is randomly sampled from three values in "sample.vect".  My aim is to have rnormfunc() sample r.dat across each row using the apply() family of functions, and return a single value for each row in a vector.  If I manually input rnormfunc(4001,0,1,3.92), the output is a value between 1900 and 2100. Am I explaining this well?  thanks for your help!